# Django field that can be either IntegerField or DecimalField

Tags: django, django-models, django-crispy-forms

In one of my Django model, I have a field that can be either an `IntegerField` or a `DecimalField` based on the user.

When the value of the record is an integer, the form should only display/edit it without trailing digits. When the value of the record has decimals, all decimals should be displayed/edit on the form.

I have tried defining this field as a DecimalField and play with the form, but the challenge is that I use `django-crispy-forms` to render my forms so I cannot use the `floatformat` filter in my template.

As a result, `5` as an integer, for instance, is displayed as `5.00000000` in my form.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this if you want to specify the amount of removed 0s:

```
{{ your_number|floatformat:"-8" }}
```

or you can also use `normalize` to remove all the trailing 0s:

```
{{ your_number.normalize }}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as I am using django-crispy-forms, my field is invoked with {{ field | as_crispy_field }}. Is there a way to achieve this at the form or model level directly?

Comment: try `{{ field.normalize | as_crispy_field}}`

Comment: Unfortunately I get a ```|as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field``` when I try that. I have tried this in different variations but all fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `round()` function. [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_round.asp)

When used without specifying a set number of decimal digits it simply removes any trailing zeroes.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the int() function when you process the form data.

Comment: But is this going to change the actual display of the value of the form without it is processed?

Comment: I think the problem is in displaying the numbers not in processing them.

Comment: When you pass data into your template you make the numbers integers, but your original data doesn't change. Would you like me to show you how it works?